# Simple Powershell Function Causing Computer Crash

Tags: excel, powershell, ms-word

I have several similar, simple Powershell function in my `$PROFILE` document that keep causing my computer to crash whenever I use them.  Using them sometimes works, but it causes everything to crash other times.

The functions simply open a `.docx` file and `.xlsx` file with Microsoft Office.  Here are the functions.  Note that some of them open more than two documents while others open programs other than Office.  The ones I think I have the most trouble with are `school-history` and `school-geometry`

```
function school-physics {
    Start-Process "$logs\Physics.xlsx"
    Start-Process "$school\Notes\Physics.docx"
    Set-Location "$school\Answers\Physics"
}

function school-history {
    Start-Process "$logs\History.xlsx"
    Start-Process "$school\Answers\History.docx"
}
function school-literature {
    Start-Process "$logs\Literature.xlsx"
    Start-Process "$school\Answers\Literature.docx"
}
function school-geometry { 
    Start-Process chrome "www.ttwebversion.com"
    Start-Process "$logs\Geometry.xlsx"
    Start-Process "$school\Notes\Geometry.docx"
}
function school-greek {
    Start-Process $logos
    Start-Process "$logs\Greek.xlsx"
    Start-Process $mnemosyne
}
```

Is the error likely in my functions, my documents (such as a corruption), or Microsoft Office?  Is there anything I can do to keep this from happening (besides opening each document the normal way or through Powershell commands that only open one at a time?

Once, after my computer crashed several times for the same function (`school-geometry`), I tried opening the documents the normal way and found that an error message came up saying that the files were probably corrupted, but it seemed that Office just assumed they were corrupted because they caused a crash several times.  I temporarily fixed the problem by copying the content into a new document, but now the error is coming up again (right now it's with `school-history`).

Comment: the usual way to load a document/sheet/whatever into an app from PoSh is to use `Invoke-Item`. it `Performs the default action on the specified item`. it LOOKS like you may be loading the _application_ multiple times with your current technique. ///// i would try adding a `Start-Sleep` between calls to load the files since the apps are quite large.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Thanks.  That seems to work.

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to have helped a tad ... [*grin*]